# Regex matching text without commas, endlines and whitespaces

Tags: regex

I need to match following text. There can't be endlines characters, whitespace characters at the beginning and the end of the text, before and after commas (but could be in the middle of the text)

I tried with `(^\S+(\S+,?\S+)?\S+$)` but it won't go with commas

Here is a link https://regexr.com/5bi4a

// SHOULD NOT MATCH

```
true, false  
true,false  
true,false 
 true ,false 
true , false 
  true , false 

Document My 
  Document my  
 Document my 
 $$ MMM yyyy - HH:mm
```

// SHOULD MATCH

```
$$ MMM yyyy - HH:mm
Document my
Drag and Drop
FIRST,SECOND,THIRD true true,false hello,txt,yyy hello,txt 01/Jan/1990
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^\S+(?: \S+)*$` https://regex101.com/r/GH7Ym4/1

Comment: There can't be spaces between commas

https://regex101.com/r/GH7Ym4/2

Comment: If there can be multple comma's `^[^\s,]+(?:,+[^,\s]+)*(?: [^\s,]+(?:,+[^,\s]+)*)*$` https://regex101.com/r/dcxiV8/1

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^\s,]` matching any character except a whitespace char or a comma. This part can be at the start and at the end of the pattern so that it can not start or end with a space or comma.

In the repeating parts you can precede the match with a comma or space.

```
^[^\s,]+(?:,+[^,\s]+)*(?: [^\s,]+(?:,+[^,\s]+)*)*$
```

The pattern will match

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\s,]+` Match 1+ times any char except a comma or whitespace char
- `(?:,+[^,\s]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching a comma and again 1+ times any char except a comma or whitespace char
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[^\s,]+` Match a space and 1+ times any char except a comma or whitespace char
  - `(?:,+[^,\s]+)*` Repeat the previous preceded by a comma
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dcxiV8/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 '^[^ ].*[^ ]$'
```

`^` <-- Start of record
`[^ ]` <-- Not space
`.*` <-- Any char string
`[^ ]$` <-- not ending with space

Demo:

```
$cat temp       
true, false  
true,false  
true,false 
 true ,false 
true , false 
  true , false 

Document My 
  Document my  
 Document my 
 $$ MMM yyyy - HH:mm

$$ MMM yyyy - HH:mm
Document my
Drag and Drop
FIRST,SECOND,THIRD true true,false hello,txt,yyy hello,txt 01/Jan/1990
$ grep '^[^ ].*[^ ]$' < temp    
$$ MMM yyyy - HH:mm
Document my
Drag and Drop
FIRST,SECOND,THIRD true true,false hello,txt,yyy hello,txt 01/Jan/1990
$
```

Comment: I can't have space before and after comma
https://regex101.com/r/GH7Ym4/2